matplotlib graph giving me a super strange result
Essentially I've got 2 sets of experimental data in separate arrays. In the first array there are some errors so im filtering them out and putting all the non erroneous data into 2 arryays (for convenience when troubleshooting). When plotting the 2 sets of data I get a super strange graph with a black bar running across the y axis graph image. I then changed the axis round so that I get the following swapped axis graph which shows the black bar must be to do with the formatting of my graph. Does anyone know how it needs to be reformatted to get rid of it :)

Your data points are strings, not numbers. See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/ticks_too_many.html#example-2-strings-can-lead-to-very-many-ticks
